# CUDA Jacobian Relaxation

Tags: cuda, gpu

I am in the process of mapping this sequential computation to a CUDA computation. This computation is a 2-dimensional Jacobian relaxation on an NxN grid, where N is unknown. N is evenly divisible by 32.

```
Jacobi(float *a,float *b,int N){
   for (i=1; i<N+1; i++){
      for (j=1; j<N+1; j++) {
         a[i][j]=0.8*(b[i+1][j]+b[i+1][j]+b[i][j+1]+b[i][j+1]);
      }
   }
}
```

I'm parallelizing the outer two loops, and each thread should compute just one element. The goal is to parallelize it to use a cyclic distribution in the the x and y dimensions. Can some one aid me in implementing a Jacobi_GPU that has the appropriate indexing functions in CUDA that results in the following distribution?

```
dim3 dimGrid(N/32,N/32);
dim3 dimBlock(32,32);
Jacobi_GPU<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(A,B,N)
```

Comment: Is the equations correct? `b[i+1][j]+b[i+1][j]+b[i][j+1]+b[i][j+1]` same as `2*b[i+1][j]+2*b[i][j+1]`. Correct?

Comment: Yeah, those would be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forThis is the simple implementation. You can use shared memory optimization for this kernel function

```
__global__ void jacobi(int* a, const int* b,const int N)
{
  int i= blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
  if (i<N && j<N)
  {
    a[j*N+i] = 0.8* (2*b[(i+1)+j*N] + 2*b[i+N*(j+1)]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you want to use "arrays of arrays" rather than arrays:

```
__global__ void Jacobi(int** a, const int** b,const int N)
{
  int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
  if (i<N && j<N)
  {
    a[i][j]=0.8*(b[i+1][j]+b[i+1][j]+b[i][j+1]+b[i][j+1]);
  }
}
```